# Comparing device SIM phone number with the user entered phone number

Tags: ios, swift, sim-card, core-telephony

As per my research and lot of others answers, we are sure that Apple is not allowing the developers to fetch phone number associated with the SIM in device.

But I'm wonder how PhonePe saying "**Please enter the phone number which is in this device**", when we are not able to fetch? What's the mechanism they are using?

PhonePe initially asking phone number, I have entered a mobile phone number (which is not in device), it asked for OTP and entered the OTP which I got for that phone number, now while verifying / linking the bank account, phonepe initiates some SMS verification and suddenly it says above messages, can you guys explain me how they are doing it.

How they are comparing the login phone number and the phone number in device? What information they are sending in that SMS? Is there any silent notification was being triggered to show that message? Are they using any unique device id binding with phone number?

I saw this in ChatGPT: In some cases, certain apps, especially financial and banking apps, may have secure agreements or partnerships with mobile carriers. This could allow them to perform additional verification checks to ensure that the phone number entered during the account linking process matches the one associated with the SIM card.

If anybody knows the process please explain me.

Comment: U have mentioned that ```phonepe initiates some SMS verification```. So if u are asked to send an SMS to their server, they have the number SMS is sent and the number u have entered. If those does not match it may show the alert

Comment: Hi @udi, I have the same thing in my mind, but there is some other case here, you have given the phone number and you got OTP, you logged in with that and linked the bank accounts as well since the phone number you gave for OTP is same as in device. Now, uninstall and re-install the app, if SIM is changed it is asking to enter phone number otherwise it's just asking passcode and directly login with all the bank accounts are readily available.

Comment: "phonepe initiates some SMS verification", can you describe this part more

Comment: Hi @Piepants, after login into app with OTP verification, to do transactions we need fetch the bank accounts which are associated with the phone number. To fetch the bank accounts, we need to select a bank from the list provided in phone pe, after selecting the bank account, phonepe creates one token and send SMS to some phone number (may be to the bank number). After that I don't know how there are getting callback, but they will display the respected message by finding the login phone number is same as SMS phone number.

Comment: then it may check if the network provider  has changed or something like that. Or else some sort of ML algorithm to track the users behaviour. (Recently I have worked in an app where the user will be asked to sign in again if his GPS locations has changed too much)

Comment: Network provider will be same, even if user switches to different phone number of same provider.